# How to isolate my browser?

Tags: permissions, security, selinux

I want to protect my data against a browser exploit, by forbidding Firefox to access any file beside :

- ~/.mozilla/
- ~/Downloads/

I tried to create another user account with which I would run Firefox with `sudo`, but it's just too complicated and not practical.

A more natural way seems to be SELinux, as I think it's the kind of situation it is supposed to handle. But I have no idea how to configure it.

As I run Fedora, SELinux is already enabled and protecting some parts of the system. Can I use it to protect my home folder as I said ?

Any other solution is welcome as well.

Comment: do a `lsof | grep firefox | awk ' { print $10 } ' | sort | uniq` and you will see that Firefox needs access to many other files besides the two you mentioned. So perhaps you should start here : https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Sandbox for example and try to understand first what is it that you want before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparmor does exactly what you're asking.

You can explicitly allow/deny which file firefox can read/write/execute

[See here for more help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#How_can_I_enable_AppArmor_for_Firefox.3F)

Answer (score -1):

You can using apparmor 
Or better selinux for this porpose 
By they yiu can garanti just your software have access to the folder
Another way is using chattr . But it not safer then apparmor v selinux